# Use of unassigned local variable - but I know that by the time the program reaches it, it will be assigned

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

So, I have this section of code:

```
void Readfile()
{
    using (reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string line = "";
        DataTable table;

        // Search for relevant "tables" in the file
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("!"))
            {
                table = CreateDataTable(reader, line);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToTable(table); // Error: "Unassigned local variable"
            }
        }
    }
}

DataTable CreateDataTable(StreamReader reader, string line)
{
    if (line.Contains("!CUST"))
    {
        DataTable custTable = new DataTable();
        custTable.TableName = "Customer";

        string[] columns = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(9));

        foreach (string s in columns)
        {
            custTable.Columns.Add(s);
        }
        return custTable;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The file this program is reading from will *always* be in this format:

```
!Line1
Line2
Line3
!Line4
[etc...]
```

So *I know* that this code is sound, in terms of "flow". It will always Create the Table first, before it adds to it. However, the way I have structured the code clearly doesn't work.

My original idea was that if I did create the DataTable before hand, (I.e. `DataTable table = new DataTable();`) then there would be an empty table floating around.

How should this be written?

Comment: you know what will be there in line. but compiler doesn't. it always care about if and else part both.

Comment: If you've produced a situation where it's impossible that your program will ever be fed an ill-formed file, congratulations. However, it's supremely unlikely that that is true. So what you "know" to be true isn't actually.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever apt name haha. And I suppose, you are correct, since there *is* a user element in this haha

Comment: what's the purpose of `Readfile` ? it looks it has no output (neither via return value nor via side effects (assigning variable with higher scope)).

Comment: @Spotted this is only halfway through development.

Comment: Another consideration, what do you do with datatable containg data from `Line1, Line2, Line3` when you encounter `Line4` ? It is lost right ? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Spotted, again, that is not the issue I am dealing with in this situation. I have taken an excerpt from my code, relevant to the problem.

Comment: Okay, I was asking these questions because I am willing to help you beyond your initial question. Indeed, the fact that you have been brought to ask this question is a sign that something might be wrong, designly speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know, but not a compiler, so initialize it with `null`:

```
DataTable table = null;
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course! I've definitely been at this for too long today

Answer (score 0):

**you are getting lines from a `file`. which can be any file.** (
if it is going in production and user changes that file - even you as programmer will not be sure that first line will starts with !)

Initially you have kept `table` unassigned and 
here on this line,

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("!"))
    {
        table = CreateDataTable(reader, line);
    }
    else
    {
        AddToTable(table); // Error: "Unassigned local variable"
    }
}
```

you are either creating a table or calling `AddToTable` method passing table into that.

you know that file is having such data that first line of file will always starts with "!" , but compiler cannot be sure with that fact at compile time.

So as there are two cases in while loop : if and else. there are equal chances that flow will either go in if or in else.

So compiler will always get worried that at first iteration if flow goes in `else` part, by that time `table` will not be assigned to any value (not even null). So it generated compile time error.

to avoid such error as **Backs suggested**, initailize table will null (which will be the best solution)

```
DataTable table = null;
```

and when you are doing so, for the sake of being in safe side, you should check for `table` is not null in `AddToTable` method at first line.

```
void AddToTable(DataTable table)
{
    if(table != null)
    {
         //your logic
    }
}
```